# Cloudflare redirect to https://www

Tags: apache, https, cloudflare

I enabled SSL in cloudflare on Flexible option, and I set Automatic HTTPS rewrites to ON.

I want the following:

example.com

www.example.com

http://example.com

http://www.example.com

to redirect all of them to

https://www.example.com

What are the redirect rules that I have to add inside cloudflare website?
I tried to write rules inside .htaccess but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```